# File or Reference not found

Tags: c#, .net

Our Company uses a Libary named Chilkat for Filetransport via FTP in an Windows Service.

The Windows Service is deployed on different Servers.

On one of the Server the we get an Exception that

> the File or Assembly "Chilkat45.dll" is not found

The original german Exception Message is:

> Die Datei oder Assembly "ChilkatDotNet46.dll" oder eine Abhängigkeit davon wurde nicht gefunden. Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.
>   Dateiname: "ChilkatDotNet46.dll"

I am sorry unlocalize.com had not the exact english equivalent message.

> The Assembly is located in the same Folder where the bin is located.

On another Server the Software runs well, and the Assembly is found.

As ChilkatDotNet46.dll should be found, how can i exactly find out, what reference is missing on the Target System?

Comment: Translation foo suggests:  "The file or assembly XXX or a dependency of it was not found. The specified module was not found."

Comment: How do you deploy your service to these servers? It sounds like you're just missing an assembly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Fusion logger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/fuslogvw-exe-assembly-binding-log-viewer) to check what files are required and what is not working when an assembly is being loaded.

> **Fuslogvw.exe (Assembly Binding Log Viewer)**
>
> The Assembly Binding Log Viewer displays details for assembly binds. This information helps you diagnose why the .NET Framework cannot locate an assembly at run time. These failures are usually the result of an assembly deployed to the wrong location, a native image that is no longer valid, or a mismatch in version numbers or cultures. The common language runtime's failure to locate an assembly typically shows up as a TypeLoadException in your application.